# ROS2 conversion of .msg files into .idl files

Tags: ros, ros2, dds

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have currently a faint understanding of the ROS2 system. I read that in ROS2 the msg files are converted into idl files before publishing and then these idl files are used for publishing and subscribing. In this image, how can i understand the circled part, ROS to DDS conversion functions...shouldnt there be an arrow as shown ? e.g. with help of these conversion functions, idl files are generated from msg files ?

[image: conversion]

I need to somehow access these idl or msg files and perform read and write operations ? Is there a possibility that i can do that ? Are there some examples ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/293144/ros2-conversion-of-.msg-files-into-.idl-files/) by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 667 on 2018-06-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The diagram only indicates how the information flows. The conversion functions mapping ROS messages to DDS messages are being generated for each DDS implementation (using their native vendor-specific DDS types). As input these templates only need the message definitions - it doesn't need any information from the `.idl` files - since those are generated from the message definitions themselves they don't contain any more information.

For the generated source code there is a dependency from the conversion functions on the DDS message classes as they are in e.g. C++ being included.

I am not sure what "read and write operations" you are intending to do. You will find the `.idl` files after building a package under `<install>/share/<pkgname>/msg|srv/dds_connext|dds_opensplice`. They are being generated and installed by the [rosidl_generator_dds_idl](https://github.com/ros2/rosidl_dds/tree/master/rosidl_generator_dds_idl) package.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2018-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [golizheh_66](https://answers.ros.org/users/46944/golizheh_66/) on 2019-11-01**:
Could explain how can I use rosidl_generator_dds_idl  packages?
I want to convert image.msg to image.idl
Thanks and look forward to hearing from you

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2019-11-03**:
You don't need to invoke `rosidl_generator_dds_idl` directly. It is being trigger implicitly when your message package calls `rosidl_generate_interfaces()`.